# Why does the display name of my users keep reverting in Firebase with swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I encountered the following error in my swift project: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4393. To overcome this issue I change the display name to the characters before the @ in a users email like so:

```swift
var displayName = user.email!
if let atRange = displayName.range(of: "@") {
    displayName.removeSubrange(atRange.lowerBound.. < displayName.endIndex)
}
if user.displayName!.count < 2{
    let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
    changeRequest?.commitChanges {(err) in
        if let err = err{
            print(err)
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I first log in but if I log out and then back in again the display name reverts back to `Optional("")`. Why would it be doing this?

**Edit**

I created a workaround where I run the above code not only when a user is first created, but every time a user logs in, this seems excessive though and there must be a reason why the display name keeps getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is intended behaviour from Apple's side. By default, you should be updating the Firebase user with the appropriate display name rather than relying on 3rd party information since these are only available on first login.

Simply checking if the name exists on initial login and is longer than 0 characters, not null, etc. then you can update the name with the following:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

This is also documented within the git-issue you posted https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4393#issuecomment-612193703

Ultimately, you are logging into your app as a Firebase user, not an apple user. Apple is only Authenticating the process, so you must update the Firebase user where possible as Apple is highly inconsistent across all platforms.

Comment: That is not what I was asking. I am aware of the issue that was referenced in the Github link I posted. As I stated in my question firebase reverts the users' display name to a blank value after it has been changed.

Comment: then you should debug the name is actually defined before sending it to firebase and ensuring you are using the latest major version of Firebase. Firebase wouldn't revert changes back, it doesn't care unless something is malformed with the request.